# substr cut text end of sentence as opposed to end of word

Tags: php, regex, substring, truncate

I have working code to chop text at the end of a word, but I am looking for end of a sentence so looking for a .(full stop) (space) rather than just a space. I also need to keep the html formatting of the text so it could be several list items in their too.

Code to truncate word:

```
$description_excerpt = preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/', '', substr($description_excerpt, 0, 200));
echo $description_excerpt;
```

Assuming $description_excerpt equals:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

<ul>
    <li>One. </li>
    <li>two. </li>
</ul>
<p>More text... </p>
```

Then when it is run through the truncator it will return this:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

<ul>
    <li>One</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: I think if you update your question with input and expected output it might be easier to understand.

Comment: @DavidStarkey sorry, updated

Comment: @JoshBoothe: I think it should output `</ul>` at the end.

Comment: Add `g` to the end of your regex? `/\s+?(\S+)?$/g`

Comment: @DavidStarkey sorry didnt see you edited, trying now

Comment: @DavidStarkey that returns nothing, surely the g should be inside the trailing `/`?

Comment: Nope, it means the search should be global.  Without the output you are wanting, we can only speculate.  So, see this example and if you continue having trouble consider adding the output you are wanting: http://regexr.com?356vu

Comment: @DavidStarkey In php, there is no `g` modifier. When *matching*, `preg_match()` is used. For global matching there is `preg_match_all()`. While *replacing*, php will automatically replace all.

Comment: @JoshBoothe If you got "nothing" when placing the `g` modifier that means you disabled error reporting which is *bad* while developing. Turn it on please to prevent any headache later. Also what you want is really tough with regex if not impossible. I think you should change your strategy and consider a robust html parser.

Answer (score 0):

Shortening HTML text is not so simple. Sure would like to have the actual length of text, not the text with HTML tags. In your example, 25 characters occupy `<p> <ul> <li>`. But let's leave it at the end.

The best solution would be a two-stage operation. Find `'. '` and 2: close tags.

```
$description_excerpt = preg_replace('/(\.)\s+[^\.]*$/', '\1', 
                                    substr($description_excerpt, 0, 200));

preg_match_all('/<(?P<close>\/)?(?P<tag>\w+)(?P<atr>[^>]*)>/', 
               $description_excerpt, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($m);
```

Now you just have to see which tags require closing. I recommend queue using `array_shift` and `array_unshift`. (and remember, the tags that do not require closure)

If you want to be closer to the exact length of the text, this first divide the text into sections: text and HTML tags. Then make sure that the more you can extend the content. If not, close the tags.